# Unable to import grails 3 project in intellij idea community edition

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I was trying to import grails 3 project in intellij idea community edition

I am getting below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.android.tools.idea.project.messages.AbstractSyncMessages.removeMessages(AbstractSyncMessages.java:79) at 
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.messages.GradleSyncMessages.removeProjectMessages(GradleSyncMessages.java:50) at 
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.notification.GradleNotificationExtension.customize(GradleNotificationExtension.java:57) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.notification.ExternalSystemNotificationManager.createNotification(ExternalSystemNotificationManager.java:168) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.createFailureResult(ExternalSystemUtil.java:651) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$3.onFailure(ExternalSystemUtil.java:517) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.onFailure(ExternalSystemProgressNotificationManagerImpl.java:124) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:94) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:542) at 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:605) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85) at 
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144) at 
com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:565) at 
com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)  
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185387.

Comment: Hi CrazyCoder, this issue is not as mentioned in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185387

I have found the root cause and have answered the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to the gradle wrapper not configured at gradle_home and instead of referring to the gradle wrapper if I am setting the gradle manually to local installed gradle this is working fine.

Comment: Where did you do this?

Answer (score 17):

For me it was a broken (?) link to the JVM, using JAVA_HOME instead of Project JVM solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by changing the gradle jvm to JAVA_HOME.